# Interactive, vertical line annotations on CanvasJS graph

Tags: javascript, graph, canvasjs

I'm trying to add annotations to my CanvasJS graph in a way similar to dygraphs' functionality( [example here](http://dygraphs.com/annotations.html)) but haven't found a way to. I've seen an example where they replaced a point with an image ([here](https://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/annotations/)) but it isn't quite the same, as I need the marker between points and to have it's own tooltip. Is there any way to achieve this in CanvasJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [indexLabels](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/indexlabel/) along with [indexLabelLineThickness](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/indexlabellinethickness/) to show annotation but toolTip are shown only for dataPoints.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
title: {
 text: "Line Chart with Index-Labels"
},
data: [{
 type: "line",
 indexLabelBackgroundColor: "LightBlue",
 indexLabelLineThickness: 1,    
 dataPoints: [
  { x: 10, y: 71 },
  { x: 20, y: 55, indexLabel: "{y}" },
  { x: 30, y: 50 },
  { x: 40, y: 65 },
  { x: 50, y: 95 },
  { x: 60, y: 68, indexLabel: "{y}" },
  { x: 70, y: 28 },
  { x: 80, y: 34, indexLabel: "{y}" },
  { x: 90, y: 14 }
 ]
}]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 250px; width: 100%;"></div>
```